# Laravel empty the request without redirect

Tags: php, laravel-5, request

In Laravel 5.8, I have a form with multiple search parameters. If a user clicks reset I want to reset all request values. In my Controller index():

```
if ($request->input('reset')) {
    $request->flush();
}
```

However when I check $request after flush the values are still present. So if I return the view() the request is still present. However if I redirect the user back to the index the request has cleared successfully. Is there a way to empty the request without calling a redirect?

Comment: Hey, Is it possible for you to reset form using JavaScript ?, That would be easy and less time taking process

Comment: You can perform `return redirect()->back();` on reset click